# How to draw rectangle marker in leaflet given only 1 [lat,lon] pair and sizes a and b in meters

Tags: leaflet

I need to draw a rectangle around a point in leaflet map. The point is a pair [lat,lon] and I have the sizes of the sides of the rectangle in meters. How can I easily do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the point will be in the center of the rectangle, you can try use the [Leaflet.GeometryUtil's destination](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#destination) to find bounds add rectangle based on the bounds. Not tested.

```
var latlng = L.latLng(lat, lon);

//Assuming rectangle has side A and side B
hypotenuse = Math.sqrt((0.5*lengthofA)**2 + (0.5*lengthofB)**2) 
swAngle = 90 + Math.atan(lengthofA/lengthofB)*180/Math.PI
neAngle = 0 - Math.atan(lengthofA/lengthofB)*180/Math.PI

var southWest = destination(latlng, swAngle, hypotenuse) //returns point L.latlng
var northEast = destination(latlng, neAngle, hypotenuse)
var bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
var rectangle = L.rectangle(bounds).addTo(map);
```